# Why doesn't my question show up in unanswered questions when filtering by tag?

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions

I asked a question on SO today, like I have many times in the past.  However, today's question was different in that it does not show up in the unanswered section when filtering by tag.

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470742/python-nonblocking-read-from-stdout-of-threaded-subprocess/2470821#2470821)

[This is where I would expect it to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python)

Can anyone clue me in as to why it wouldn't be showing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an upvoted answer on your question. Note the text on the right side of the unanswered-questions-page:

> 1,173 questions **with no upvoted answers** tagged with python

I admit, I sat here scratching my head for a moment too :) Even tried a more unique tag "nonblocking," which had 7 results, none of which was your question. Turns out, having even 1 upvoted answer removes you from the "unanswered" page.

Comment: +1 Ah Ha!  I thought they had to have an accepted answer.  Oh well, hopefully someone will still come along and find me :)

Comment: @sberry2A: It used to confuse me too, since *technically* there are answers. But as @dmckee pointed out, there is a blog post explaining the reasoning behind this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Answer (score 1):

"Unanswered" means having no upvoted answers. That question has upvoted answers ergo it does not appear in the Unanswered list.

There is a [blog post on the matter](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) around here somewhere...

Comment: +1 For quick blog-referencing!